# Does the operator [] of std::vector<type> walk through the vector from the beginning on each call

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, vector, stl

I see many programmers using `std::vector<type>::operator[]`  to access the vector's elements in a `for` loop this way :

```
for (int c=0;c<vect.size();c++)
{
   vect[c] ....
}
```

but when i use ieterators i get a better performance can you explain why ?

```
for (std::vector<type>::iterator it = vect.begin();it<vect.end();it++)
{
  *it = ...
]
```

a possible reason that can be wrong it that the operator `[]` works like in the case of a linked list , it is navigating through the vector till reaching the element of the desired index

Comment: Do you have any reason to "think it is working like the case of a linked list"?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at

Comment: That is *completely **wrong***.

Comment: i have just edited the question to answer you

Comment: so the question is how does the operator [] work ?

Comment: "because i know the vectors are using nodes and pointers like the linked list" - This is completely wrong! Where did you hear this? A vector allocates a single continuous block of memory to store all elements in, so indexed access is just a pointer offset.

Comment: "i know the vectors are using nodes and pointers like the linked list" is not even an assuption, it is an assertion and it is wrong.

Comment: ok thanks fr noting , im not talking aboutthe std::vector class , i am talking about the common implementation of vectors

Comment: C++ does have linked lists, but they're called `std::list` and `std::forward_list`. (The normal list can also iterate backwards, i.e. `std::list::iterator supports both ++ and --)

Comment: @HassenDhia - the common implementation of `std::vector` uses an array, and the index operator goes directly to the appropriate element. If you're seeing a performance difference between direct indexing and iterators you'll have to post your benchmark code so that people can see how it does the timing. Chances are there's something else going on in that code; there's no reason for iteration to be faster than indexing.

Comment: How did you measure the claimed difference in speed? Can you provide a minimal example that reproduces your findings? What happens in the body of your for loop? Is the size of `vect` modified (i.e. by adding or removing elements)? We cannot help you without detailed information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access time in `vector` with the `[]` operator is constant.

That means it is *not* working its way through any kind of list.
There is no need at all, vector is implemented as a malloced array; all `vector` adds to it is the automatic resizing, which just means that it makes another malloc and copies the content for you, without introducing errors.
You can see that yourself by open the include `<vector>`.

Comment: ok , but get better performance when using iterators , cann you tell why ?

Comment: `vector` doesn't use `malloc`. It's a class template parametrized on an allocator.

Answer (score 1):

There are rules about the minimum complexity for operations, so any implementation that did this would be non standard compliant afaik.

In other words, no it does not.

See the complexity section for members of containers:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/

Here it says constant. This means that the size of the vector and the accessed element should have no effect on the time it takes.

**Possible answer to edit:** If you are building with debug information the `operator[]` and the `at()` function will take a lot longer because they do a range check each time (avoided when using the `iterator`).

Comment: What it the possible internal implemation to make it that fast , if not working as a linked list .

Comment: Perhaps a plain array?

Comment: @HassenDhia it can be implemented as ever people want as long as it satisfies the requirements. But you should read up on pointers and arrays if you don't know about this.

Comment: The start pointer of the array is known. So when you ask for item 5, it just adds 5 to the starting pointer for the array, which gives the memory location of the item at index 5. Probably.

Comment: I dont think it is an array because it is more dynamic than that , i mean not of a constant size , even if it was a dynamic array resizeing it will take a bit of time , so i think it is a linked list , and i think iterators are acting like pointers to nodes

Comment: @HassenDhia. All implementations I have seen are just arrays. The initial size of that array is not the same as the externally visible number of items (it will probably be greater). When you want to put more items into the array than the initial capacity it will copy the whole array to a new location, with an extra N size added onto the end. The data is more or less certain to be contiguous in memory in any implementation as far as I know.

Comment: @sji: `std::vector` is contiguous, no uncertainty about that. That is to say, `&vec[A] - &vec[B] == A - B`.